# How to get the list all users in confluence using rest API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to get the list of all users with their email addresses from a confluence cloud instance using their REST API. There is nothing in their documentation regarding users. Also the **email address** is never embedded in any of the response containing user objects. Is there a way to retrieve email address of the user based on the username.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use their older APIs -- [the methods are there](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-xml-rpc-and-soap-apis/remote-confluence-methods#RemoteConfluenceMethods-UserManagement).

Comment: Thank you, it seems like the only way to go. Also, could you please help me find a way where I can call the XML-RPC methods using OAuth 1.0 generated tokens rather than generating the token from username and password.

Comment: Never tried that, sorry.  What happens if you just pass the requisite `Authorization:` header?

Comment: I don't think so. All the Remote APIs require a token argument which is the String returned from another remote call confluence2.login(username, password)